# Insert Data From Datagridview the correct way. c# Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

If i want to insert from datagridview into MYSQl Database, it injects into different columns instead of the correct columns.

My table looks like this :

> id | visit_date | visitor_name | visit_address | visit_city |
>   signin_time | vehicle_number | organization | visit_type | reason |
>   id_type | person_visit | img | signout_time

Code looks like this :

```
private void confirmAppointmentToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLDatabaseConnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open();
        string sql = "insert into vms_db.final_appointments(visit_date,visitor_name,signin_time,vehicle_number,organization,visit_type,reason,id_type,person_visit,img) values (@visit_date,@visitor_name,@signin_time,@vehicle_number,@organization,@visit_type,@reason,@id_type,@person_visit,@img)";

        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visit_date", System.DateTime.Now);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visitor_name", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visit_address", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visit_city", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@signin_time", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vehicle_number", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@organization", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visit_type", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reason", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_type", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@person_visit", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Final Appointments Reserved, You may Exit Window", "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    Close();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it doesn't insert into the correct columns. I got tempted, and since I want to be sure of what I am doing, I am asking if I can correctly insert into the database via this means :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visitor_name", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["visitor_name"].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visit_address", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["visit_address"].Value);
```

Comment: This code cannot work correctly. You use the same command for all rows but you add parameters without clearing them at each loop. This will result in errors while adding the parameters in the second row or many records added with the same value

Comment: @Steve what i mean is, it submits to the database, but instead of inserting into say organization, its going to take the value for Organization and save in signin_time.

Comment: Of course you need to be certain that the column indexes you are using match effectively the parameter at which you assign the values. Remember that array indexes starts at zero, so the first column is at index 0, the second column is at index 1 and so on.

Comment: Since you ask for the "correct" way, I would argue you should consider using data binding instead of accessing rows of the grid. A properly configured MySqlDataAdapter can insert, update and delete the database with a single call to it's `Update()` method and you never have to manually get any row/cell values.

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot work correctly because you use the same command for all rows but you continuosly add parameters without clearing them at each loop.
This will result in errors while adding the parameters in the second row or many records added with the same value.

You can write a better code defining the parameter once for all and then just changing the value inside the loop. And not use AddWithValue at all

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    try
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@visit_date", MySqlDbType.DateTime);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@visitor_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
        .... // add all the other parameters here

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters["@visit_date"].Value = System.DateTime.Now;

            // You need to be sure about what column contains the 
            // visitor name. Here for example you take the value 
            // from the third column, not from the second one.
            cmd.Parameters["@visitor_name"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
            ... again set the value at each loop for each parameter
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: yes its ok, only it still doesnt match the database columns when inserting data. i started to think maybe i do it like this cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visitor_name", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["visitor_name"].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visit_address", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["visit_address"].Value);

Comment: You can write the column name if it  matches the name of the fields in your database table